# Even spaces between bootstrap columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using this markup...

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="background-color:gray">1</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div style="background-color:gray">2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="background-color:gray">3</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle (run it in full screen):
http://jsfiddle.net/MojoDK/swKyX/

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

The spacing between the divs at the red arrows are double of the space of the divs at the orange arrows.

How can I make the div space at the red arrow the same space (10px) as at the orange arrows and still maintain aligned divs/blocks when the three divs wraps as the browser window becomes smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.row > div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    padding: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row > div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
}
```

This will work fine in a three columned layout.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. But what if there's two columns? - then I have the problem again.

Comment: Then you have to set the `padding-right` of `div:first-child` and the `padding-left` of `div:last-child` to the half value in the non-mobile variant.

Comment: But the css doesn't know if I'm using 2 or 12 divs?

Comment: The, CSS does never know if there are 2 or 12 divs.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this, but here's one:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
 .container-fluid{
   margin-left:15px;
   margin-right:15px;    
 }
}
```

Here is a fiddle (note you can import the bootstrap CSS for future reference):

http://jsfiddle.net/swKyX/5/

Comment: How would I change all the "margins" to 10px (at the red arrows too)?